# grails spring security core

Tags: grails, authentication

I have built a mobile app that logs into my grails app.
I want to log out of the session on my mobile app.

I know the url I use to log in is:

```
  http://localhost:8080/<app name>/j_spring_security_check
```

but how would i close that session and logout?
Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a GET for `http://localhost:8080/<app name>/j_spring_security_logout`